# How to scan multiple strings in one place?

Tags: c

I am working on a project. I need to get each student's courses and their number, for example:

```
Lisa Miller  890238
Mathematics  MTH345
Physics  PHY357  
ComputerSci  CSC478  
History  HIS356
```

I do not know how to register all those courses and their numbers in one place specified for that student. What should I do?

Comment: Read line-by-line, if first `token` doesn't match with any `subject` then it must be a `student-name`. But, what if a `student's name` is same as an offered `course name`? Then you can check the registered `course code`s. That said, this is tedious input. All data of a `student` should come on a line, easier for parsing.

Comment: That example I gave is from a file, the file should remain as such. I am asking if there is any data structure I can use to save all of a student's information into it, then print it inside a file as displayed.

Comment: You can use structures. Each student has a separate file?

Comment: No, it is one file with the informations of all students, as presented above, separated by a backslash. Do I just use a simple struct ?

Comment: "as presented above, separated by a backslash" --> Why post the example input then without a backslash?

Comment: SO is not a Homework Service

Comment: @chux: Probably because the input was initially posted without any formatting at all, so that it was initially necessary to remove the backslashes. The missing formatting has now been fixed by a third party. However, that third party was of course unable to insert the missing backslashes again. The OP should be able to do that now, though.

Comment: @rioV8: You are correct that Stack Overflow is not a "do my homework for me" service. However, specific questions regarding homework are generally permitted. See this question for further information: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/12149471)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need two structures:

One for the student and their list of courses, and one for a course.

Assuming you know maximum number of courses a student can take:

```
struct course {
    char name[MAX_COURSE_NAME_LEN];
    char id[MAX_COURSE_ID_LEN]; //this one should be 7
};

struct student {
    char name[MAX_STUDENT_NAME_LEN];
    unsigned int id; //student ids are all numbers, right?
    int num_courses; //number of courses student actually takes
    struct course courses[MAX_COURSES];
}
```

If you want to be memory efficient or the maximum number of courses a student can take is not specified, you should used a linked list of courses instead of an array.

You will need custom code to read this from file and write it back to a file.

C standard library does not come with serialization and deserialization functions, but if this is more than a homework project, you may want to look for a dedicated serialization library.

Comment: "This one is 6" — it had better be 7 so that a 6-character string can be stored, or the dimension needs to be `MAX_COURSE_ID_LEN + 1`.  The student structure probably needs a count of the courses for this student too.

Answer (score 0):

Here are steps you can follow:

- define a structure for student courses with these fields:

  - a pointer to the next student course
  - a pointer to the course name
  - a string for the course ID
- define a structure for the student with these fields:

  - a pointer to the next student
  - a string pointer for their name
  - an integer for their student ID
  - a pointer to a list of courses
- define a pointer to a list of students, initialized to `NULL`
- in a loop: read the file one line at time

  - trim trailing spaces
  - locate the last word
  - if it starts with a digit:

    - allocate a new student structure and link it at the end of the student list.
    - convert the number as the student number using `strtoul()`
    - copy the beginning of the line as the student name using `strdup()`
  - otherwise the line is a course:

    - allocate a new student course and link it at the end of the current student's course list
    - copy the word as the course ID using `sscanf()`
    - copy the beginning of the line as the course name using `strdup()`

Constraints:

- do not use `strtok()`
- do not use `strcpy()`
- prevent all buffer overflows
- detect malformed input and output a meaningful error message

You can write a printing routine to print the complete student list and compare the output with the file contents for validation.